# Equivalent of explode() to work with strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I want to be able to search for `'31 - 7'`, when another value = `'7 - 31'`.  What is the syntax that I would use to break apart strings in MySQL?  In PHP, I would probably use `explode(' - ',$string)` and put them together.  Is there a way to do this in MySQL?

Background: I'm working with sports scores and want to try games where the scores are the same (and also on the same date) - the listed score for each team is backwards compare to their opponent's database record.

The ideal MySQL call would be:

```
Where opponent1.date  = opponent2.date
  AND opponent1.score = opponent2.score
```

(`opponent2.score` would need to be `opponent1.score` backwards).

Comment: From the looks of it, I think you may have some fundamental flaws in your database design. Can you show us the schema of relevant tables as well as sample data for them?

Comment: Isn't it the time to accept the answer?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

MYSQL has no `explode()` like function built in. But you can easily add similar function to your DB  and then use it from php queries. That function will look like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STRING(str VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), pos INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos),
       CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos-1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

Usage:

```
SELECT SPLIT_STRING('apple, pear, melon', ',', 1)
```

The example above will return `apple`.
I think that it will be impossible to return array in MySQL so you must specify which occurrence to return explicitly in `pos`. Let me know if you succeed using it.

Comment: The delimiter parameter datatype size VARCHAR(12) should be larger than 12 so it does not produce unpredictable results with larger delimiters.

Comment: I need to declare this function as DETERMINISTIC in one of my servers. Like here:
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
RETURN

Comment: Use: SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;

before execute above query, if you got "This function has none of DETERMINISTIC" error.

Comment: Nice function, but you should [replace `LENGTH()` with `CHAR_LENGTH()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816726/mysql-function-to-split-strings-by-delimiter-doenst-work-with-polish-special-ch), if you work with multi-byte character sets.

Comment: @Boolean_Type Thanks, I haven't taken into account unicode characters/symbols that take variable length.

Answer (score 83):

I try with `SUBSTRING_INDEX(string,delimiter,count)`

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', 2);
-> 'www.mysql'

mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', -2);
-> 'mysql.com'
```

see more on mysql.com
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: This seems simple and works well on www.www.www.www.example.com to get to just example.com.

Answer (score 34):

You can use stored procedure in this way..

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE explode( pDelim VARCHAR(32), pStr TEXT)                                
BEGIN                                
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_explode;                                
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_explode (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, word VARCHAR(40));                                
  SET @sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO temp_explode (word) VALUES (', REPLACE(QUOTE(pStr), pDelim, '\'), (\''), ')');                                
  PREPARE myStmt FROM @sql;                                
  EXECUTE myStmt;                                
END |   

DELIMITER ;
```

- example call:

  ```
   SET @str  = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"; 
   SET @delim = " "; 

  CALL explode(@delim,@str);
  SELECT id,word FROM temp_explode;
  ```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is incredibly brilliant or incredibly dangerous.

Comment: incredibly brillient

Comment: I need to do in `MySQL` as I do in `SQL-SERVER` with this `SELECT * FROM dbo.SPLIT_INT('1414,1412,1416,1411,1415,1413',',')`

Answer (score 18):

First of all you should change database structure - the score in this case is some kind of composite value and should be stored in two columns, eg. `score_host`, `score_guest`.

---

MySQL doesn't provide `explode()` equivalent however in this case you could use [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) and [`LOCATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) to cut off score of a host and a guest.

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(SUBSTRING(score, 1, LOCATE('-',score) - 2) USING INTEGER) as score_host,
   CONVERT(SUBSTRING(score, LOCATE('-',score)+2) USING INTEGER) as score_guest
FROM ...;
```

[`CONVERT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) is used to cast a string `"23"` into number `23`.

Answer (score 11):

Use this function. It works like a charm.

Replace `|` with the char to explode/split and the values 1, 2, 3, etc… are based on the number of entries in the data-set:
`Value_ONE|Value_TWO|Value_THREE`.

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`tblNAME`.`tblFIELD`, '|', 1), '|', -1) AS PSI,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`tblNAME`.`tblFIELD`, '|', 2), '|', -1) AS GPM,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`tblNAME`.`tblFIELD`, '|', 3), '|', -1) AS LIQUID
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: How could you get the number of items in the set?

Comment: Unfortunately not, you need to know the number of values before hand. In my case I know there are three values I need and I rename them PSI,GPM, and LIQUID. if one of the the values in the data set is empty, SQL returns an empty value without giving errors. This way I always print/echo $return-> PSI, $return->GPM, and $return->LIQUID

Comment: @Lolums You can count occurrences of the separator: `ROUND (   
        (CHAR_LENGTH(`tblNAME`.`tblFIELD`) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE ( `tblNAME`.`tblFIELD`, "|", "") ) ) / CHAR_LENGTH("|"))` Zero= length is one item (no separator), One= there are two items, etc

Answer (score 4):

use substring_index, in the example below i have created a table with column score1 and score2, score1 has 3-7, score2 7-3 etc as shown in the image. The below query is able to split using "-" and reverse the order of score2 and compare to score1

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(score1, '-', 1),
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(score1,'-',-1)
) AS my_score1,
CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(score2, '-', -1),
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(score2, '-', 1)
) AS my_score2
FROM test HAVING my_score1=my_score2
```

[image: scores table]

[image: query results]

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a modified version of the selected answer in order to support Unicode characters but I don't have enough reputation to comment there.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STRING(str VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8, delim VARCHAR(12), pos INT) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos),
       CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos-1)) + 1),
       delim, '')
```

The modifications are the following:

- The first parameter is set as `utf8`
- The function is set to return `utf8`
- The code uses `CHAR_LENGTH()` instead of `LENGTH()` to calculate the *character length* and **not** the *byte length*.

Answer (score 2):

As @arman-p pointed out MYSQL has no explode(). However, I think the solution presented in much more complicated than it needs to be. To do a quick check when you are given a comma delimited list string (e.g, list of the table keys to look for) you do:

```
SELECT 
    table_key, field_1, field_2, field_3
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    field_3 = 'my_field_3_value'
    AND (comma_list = table_key
        OR comma_list LIKE CONCAT(table_key, ',%')
        OR comma_list LIKE CONCAT('%,', table_key, ',%')
        OR comma_list LIKE CONCAT('%,', table_key))
```

This assumes that you need to also check field_3 on the table too. If you do not need it, do not add that condition.

Answer (score 1):

if explode is used together with foreach to build a new string you can simulate explode by using a while loop like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION explode_and_loop(sep VARCHAR(),inputstring VARCHAR()) RETURNS VARCHAR() 
BEGIN
    DECLARE part,returnstring VARCHAR();
    DECLARE cnt,partsCnt INT();
    SET returnstring = '';
    SET partsCnt = ((LENGTH(inputstring ) - LENGTH(REPLACE(inputstring,sep,''))) DIV LENGTH(sep);
    SET cnt = 0;
    WHILE cnt <= partsCnt DO
        SET cnt = cnt + 1;
        SET part = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(inputstring ,sep,cnt),sep,-1);
        -- DO SOMETHING with the part eg make html:
        SET returnstring = CONCAT(returnstring,'<li>',part,'</li>')
    END WHILE;
    RETURN returnstring;
END
```

this example will return a html list of the parts. (required variable legths have to be added)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem can be solved in other simpler ways. But to answer your question, you can leverage the JSON functions in order to "explode" a string.

In your particular case, the strings **'7 - 31'** and **'31 - 7'** can be reformatted into a valid JSON string combining functions **CONCAT()** and **REPLACE()**:

`SELECT CONCAT('["',REPLACE('31 - 7',' - ','","'),'"]') score`

The output will look like this:

`["31","7"]`

This is a valid JSON string.

The next step is to use the **JSON_VALUE()** function to extract each opponents score.

`SELECT JSON_VALUE(CONCAT('["',REPLACE('31 - 7',' - ','","'),'"]'),'$[0]') oponent1, JSON_VALUE(CONCAT('["',REPLACE('31 - 7',' - ','","'),'"]'),'$[1]') oponent2`

The result will look like this:

```
+-----------+----------+
| oponent1  | oponent2 |
+-----------+----------+
|       31  |        7 |
+-----------+----------+
```

Finally, you can manipulate these values as you please. Perhaps you wish to reorder them, placing the least score first so that the score is always a standard format instead of being dependent on who the home team may be.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue today and resolved it like below, please note in my case, I know the number of items in the concatenated string, hence I can recover them this way:

```
set @var1=0;
set @var2=0;
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('value1,value2', ',', 1) into @var1;
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('value1,value2', ',', -1) into @var2;
```

variables @var1 and @var2 would have the values similar to explode().

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is fully answering the question (it isn't), but it's the solution I came up with for my very similar problem.  I know some of the other solutions look shorter but they seem to use SUBSTRING_INDEX() way more than necessary. Here I try to just use LOCATE() just once per delimiter.

```
-- *****************************************************************************
-- test_PVreplace

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS test_PVreplace;

delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION test_PVreplace (
   str TEXT,   -- String to do search'n'replace on
   pv TEXT     -- Parameter/value pairs 'p1=v1|p2=v2|p3=v3'
   )
   RETURNS TEXT

-- Replace specific tags with specific values.

sproc:BEGIN
   DECLARE idx INT;
   DECLARE idx0 INT DEFAULT 1;   -- 1-origined, not 0-origined
   DECLARE len INT;
   DECLARE sPV TEXT;
   DECLARE iPV INT;
   DECLARE sP TEXT;
   DECLARE sV TEXT;

   -- P/V string *must* end with a delimiter.

   IF (RIGHT (pv, 1) <> '|') THEN
      SET pv = CONCAT (pv, '|');
      END IF;

   -- Find all the P/V pairs.

   SELECT LOCATE ('|', pv, idx0) INTO idx;
   WHILE (idx > 0) DO
      SET len = idx - idx0;
      SELECT SUBSTRING(pv, idx0, len) INTO sPV;

      -- Found a P/V pair.  Break it up.

      SELECT LOCATE ('=', sPV) INTO iPV;
      IF (iPV = 0) THEN
         SET sP = sPV;
         SET sV = '';
      ELSE
         SELECT SUBSTRING(sPV, 1, iPV-1) INTO sP;
         SELECT SUBSTRING(sPV, iPV+1) INTO sV;
         END IF;

      -- Do the substitution(s).

      SELECT REPLACE (str, sP, sV) INTO str;

      -- Do next P/V pair.

      SET idx0 = idx + 1;
      SELECT LOCATE ('|', pv, idx0) INTO idx;
      END WHILE;
   RETURN (str);
END//
delimiter ;

SELECT test_PVreplace ('%one% %two% %three%', '%one%=1|%two%=2|%three%=3');
SELECT test_PVreplace ('%one% %two% %three%', '%one%=I|%two%=II|%three%=III');
SELECT test_PVreplace ('%one% %two% %three% - %one% %two% %three%', '%one%=I|%two%=II|%three%=III');
SELECT test_PVreplace ('%one% %two% %three% - %one% %two% %three%', '');
SELECT test_PVreplace ('%one% %two% %three% - %one% %two% %three%', NULL);
SELECT test_PVreplace ('%one% %two% %three%', '%one%=%two%|%two%=%three%|%three%=III');
```

Answer (score 0):

Arman P's answer but with the function renamed to `EXPLODE`, the code better-formatted, and including boilerplate so MySQL 8 doesn't throw an error.

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION EXPLODE(str VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), pos INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN REPLACE(
        SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos),
        CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos - 1)) + 1),
        delim,
        ''
    );
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```