# How to manipulate an array value within mysql (reverse of concatenate)

Tags: php, mysql, reverse, concat-ws

In MySQL I've used the function CONCAT_WS to add a value to the textfield.

```
 UPDATE table SET `textfield`= >>CONCAT_WS('textfield',$randomnumber)<<
```

Now I've the following entry in the textfield (random numbers), for example:

> 18, 20, 30, 20, 10

Now I'd like to use a reverse version of the function CONCAT_WS.
For example, when I get number 20 (with random PHP-function) I'd like to delete ONLY the last 20 in the row.

> 18, 20, 30, 20, 10 => 18, 20, 30, 10

When I would have a MySQL-table with a row for each array value instead of a MySQL textfield array, I could do it like this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE `textfield`='20' >>LIMIT 1<<
```

How can I do the same, but with a mySQL array which I manipulate directly in the database.
For example like this:

```
UPDATE table SET `textfield`= >>DECONCAT_WS('textfield',20)<<
```

But too bad, this isn't a valid code.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: I'm curious why you are de-normalizing your data into a single field like this.  Rather than pulling it all into one field, what about a second table with a many to many relationship that achieves the same thing.  It will be a heck of a lot easier to manipulate the values you are considering.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i know:

- There is no such a function in MySQL
- There is no data-type like *array* in MySQL
- There is some [set-related string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html), which could help, but these works with only comma as separator, and nothing specifically for this problem.