# MySQL Group By single result order by time

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch users from messages table which has send message to me but need only one result per sender which is max of `creation` column which is time of message creation

```
SELECT messages.from, account_images.profile, bio.user_full_name
FROM messages
INNER JOIN account_images ON account_images.uuid=messages.from
INNER JOIN bio ON bio.uuid=messages.from
WHERE messages.to='me'
GROUP BY messages.from
ORDER BY messages.creation DESC
```

A user whose message is created recently must be on top but it not coming on top using this code. I referred [php mysql Group By to get latest record, not first record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459516/php-mysql-group-by-to-get-latest-record-not-first-record) but not getting anything 
Any help?

Comment: How are your tables structured?

Comment: Another victim of MySQL's evil `GROUP BY` behavior.

Comment: Table Structure: `id || from || to || message || creation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have written the current query as...

```
SELECT DISTINCT messages.from, account_images.profile, bio.user_full_name
FROM messages
INNER JOIN account_images ON account_images.uuid=messages.from
INNER JOIN bio ON bio.uuid=messages.from
WHERE messages.to='me'
```

Which would have been marginally more efficient - but as you will have noticed with your current query, it doesn't get sorted by the most recent message.

This is sorted as you request:

```
SELECT messages.from, account_images.profile, bio.user_full_name
FROM messages
INNER JOIN account_images ON account_images.uuid=messages.from
INNER JOIN bio ON bio.uuid=messages.from
WHERE messages.to='me'
GROUP BY messages.from
ORDER BY MAX(messages.creation) DESC;
```

It is possible to get the result you desire using DISTINCT instead of aggregation, but it's neither efficient nor elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I found this mysql doc very helpful in cases like this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-row.html

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON m.creation > m2.creation
WHERE m2.creation IS NULL
AND m1.to='me'
```