# Get most recent record from MySQL - this have many duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch the most recent record from my DB. The table looks like the below.

```
Ticket_id|  date|   comments
EWU-752-84170|  4/10/2015 13:26|bla
HCX-943-86125|  4/10/2015 13:39|    ola
IKW-626-96314|  4/10/2015 13:42|    jkj
EWU-752-84170|  4/10/2015 13:28|    blo
EWU-752-84170|  4/10/2015 13:37|    ala
HCX-943-86125|  4/10/2015 15:11|    kbdkj
EWU-752-84170|  4/10/2015 13:43|    cla
```

and the output should send the most recent records as below.

```
Ticket_id|  date|   comments
EWU-752-84170|  4/10/2015 13:43|    cla
HCX-943-86125|  4/10/2015 15:11|    kbdkj
IKW-626-96314|  4/10/2015 13:42|    jkj
```

Comment: One record? Your output looks a little confusing.

Comment: ... ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,1

Comment: @hellcode that returns a single record, o/p should remove all the duplicate ticket_id and show the most recent records against ticket_id

Comment: @JayBlanchard just edited... apologies for the bad typo

Comment: so you want the most recent grouped by `Ticket_id`

Comment: possible duplicate of [php mysql Group By to get latest record, not first record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459516/php-mysql-group-by-to-get-latest-record-not-first-record)

Comment: @Sean yeah... i got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will select all tickets where another ticket with a later date does not exist (therefore it selects only the latest tickets)

```
select * from mytable t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from mytable t2
    where t2.ticket_id = t1.ticket_id
    and t2.date > t1.date
)
```

Comment: thanks Fuzzy... this is working good.. since i have many duplicate records i just modified select 1 to select *....

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY date DESC limit 1
```

That should work fine.

Comment: this will give an top most record, but the problem is i need to remove all the duplicates from the table

Comment: Isn't that what you asked? "Get most recent record from MySQL"

Comment: apologies for my typo... i need to remove all the duplicates from the table and the time stamp should be the latest....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
  mytable t1 LEFT JOIN mytable t2
  ON
    t1.Ticket_id=t2.Ticket_id
    AND t1.date<t2.date
WHERE
  t2.date IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * from dailyhandover t1
where not exists (
    select * from dailyhandover t2
    where t2.ticket_id = t1.ticket_id
    and t2.date > t1.date
) and customer_name='bata'
```