# Mysql Group By get latest record with Count

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my customer table.

[image: Customer table]

I want to group by emp_id alongwith the count. But Group By gets the 'first' record and not the 'newest' one.

I have tried various queries, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13460492/7035903)

```
SELECT id, emp_id, COUNT( * ) AS count, created_at
FROM  customer c
WHERE  created_at = (
SELECT MAX(  created_at ) 
FROM  customer c2
WHERE c2.emp_id = c.emp_id
)
GROUP BY  emp_id 
ORDER BY  created_at DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[image]

But cannot get the count. Please help.

Edit: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120) doesn't help to obtain count

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Comment: No, I wanted count as well. No answer there.

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you please paste that?

Comment: Check the last image. But it has incorrect count values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try joining to a subquery:

```
SELECT c1.id, c1.emp_id, c1.created_at, c2.cnt
FROM customer c1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT emp_id, MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM customer
    GROUP BY emp_id
) c2
    ON c1.emp_id = c2.emp_id AND c1.created_at = c2.max_created_at;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
please try this 
SELECT cust1.id, cust1.emp_id, cust1.created_at, cust2.cnt
FROM customer cust1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT emp_id, MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM customer
    GROUP BY emp_id
) cust2
    ON cust1.emp_id = cust2.emp_id AND cust1.created_at = cust2.max_created_at;
```

Comment: This is a (broken) copy of my answer.  Plagiarism = you get downvoted.

Comment: If you need to add a new answer, please also add an explanation to the code