# How to explode in MySQL and use it in the WHERE clause of the query - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database table as below.

Promotion_Table

```
id(INT), promotion_name(VARCHAR),......, bungalow_ids(VARCHAR)
```

We can add a promotion for a bungalow(23). So a row is added with the bungalow id as below.

1, My Promotion, ........, 23

But if I single a promotion is added for a multiple bungalows(23,42) all ids are saved in the `bungalow_ids` column as below.

2, My Promotion 2, ........, 23 | 42

If a user search for promotion which are for specific bungalow(23) All promotions for the bungalow should be shown in the result.

I have a query as below.

```
SELECT * FROM Promotion_Table WHERE bungalow_ids = '23'
```

It only gets 1 rows. But actually 2nd row should be shown too since there is a offer. I can nt use `LIKE` since it gets wrong records.

Given that I have already referred below links but I have no idea how to use them in the query.

[Can you split/explode a field in a MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query)

[Equivalent of explode() to work with strings in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql)

How can I fix this? How can I explode the column data and use it in the query ?

Comment: you are really making your work harder by storing ids in a single varchar. Why not use multiple rows instead?

Comment: how it will give wrong result if you use `LIKE`.

Comment: If I use LIKE '23%' , it gives me 232,231, 231 and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `,` to separate the string and try this query

```
select * from promotion_table where FIND_IN_SET("23",bungalow_ids)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bbcb/1

Answer (score 0):

you need to reformat your DB schema.
you need to construct 2 tables one for promotions and one for bangalows.
like below:

> promotions: `Promotion_id(int)`, `Promotion_desc`
>
> bangalows:   `Bangalow_id(int)`, `Promotion_id(int)`

tables example:

**promotion :**

```
1        myPromotion     
2        secondPromotion
```

**bangalows:**

```
1     1    
2     2   
3     1   
4     1
```

once you create above two tables, the following query will work and returns 1,3,4:

```
SELECT Bangalow_id FROM Promotion_Table WHERE bungalow_id = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous Answer is the right decision but if you insist in your model.
Probably what you want to do is:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Promotion_Table
 WHERE bungalow_ids = '23'
    OR bungalow_ids LIKE '23,*'
    OR bungalow_ids LIKE '*,23'
    OR bungalow_ids LIKE '*,23,*'
```

this assuming the numbers are separated by ",".
But this is the wrong way, make the changes to the DB as stated in the previous answer.