# MySQL database : separating data of a field

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, localhost

I'm receiving text messages into PHPMyAdmin as numbers separated by commas, is there a way to separate these data into different table as each number in a different column  .

Comment: http://php.net/str_getcsv ? http://php.net/explode ?

Comment: i think is not clear what you need to achieve and by means of what. Do you mean using SQL? or by means of a php program? please, try to write your questions giving as much details as you can, so you can get more detailed answers.

Comment: The others' questions are all good, but also how is the data getting in to your database (which is technically MySQL, by the way; phpMyAdmin is simply a tool to access and administrate a MySQL database).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a purely MySQL solution, this thread should help:
[Equivalent of explode() to work with strings in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql)

But IMO, it would be easier with your own PHP application.

Comment: Thank you sir I've found a way