# split firstname and lastname but only on first space

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to split a string in MSSQL by only the first whitespace
Considering here can have 2 spaces in their full name, I have no idea how to do this.

Example:

`Henk de Vries`

I would like to split it into:

```
Firstname: Henk
Lastname: de Vries
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql

Comment: This link might be helpful to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql

Comment: Ok i've looked into the links. Do you guys know if SUBSTRING_INDEX is any comparable to CHARINDEX in mssql?

Comment: the links refering to duplicates concerns mysql. This is not a mysql question. Although the question HAS been asked before in sqlserver.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try using [Patindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188395.aspx)

```
create table #t(name varchar(20))
insert into #t values('Henk de Vries')

select substring(name,1,PATINDEX('% %',name)) as First_name,SUBSTRING(name,patindex('% %',name),LEN(name)) as Last_Name from #t
```

*This is done to fix as said in comments* by t-clausen.dk

```
select left(name,charindex(' ',name+' ')) as First_Name,substring(name,charindex(' ',name+' '),len(name)) as Last_Name from #t
```

<kbd>[An demo to test with](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18574)</kbd>

<kbd>[Updated demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18582)</kbd>

Comment: Hey thanks, I just noticed I had to use a Derrived Column (Visual studio ssis) And got the following with the help of your answer and google :) :

SUBSTRING(Name,FINDSTRING(Name," ",1) + 1,LEN(Name) - FINDSTRING(Name," ",1))

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is not the best way to handle splitting. You are assuming the data will always include a space. You can use left, stuff and charindex with better result instead

Comment: @t-clausen.dk : yes +1! i didn't see that coming as OP mentioned this _Considering here can have 2 spaces in their full name_ but yes u're right!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example that will compare this answer to the chosen answer, note that the chosen answer has bugs when there is just 1 name (I know most people have combined names, but this is not a perfect world):

```
SELECT 
  LEFT(name, charindex(char(32), name + char(32))) Firstname,
  STUFF(name, 1, charindex(char(32), name), '') LastName,
  -- included example from accepted answer
  substring(name,1,PATINDEX('% %',name)) as First_name,
  SUBSTRING(name,patindex('% %',name),LEN(name)) as Last_Name
FROM (values('Henk de Vries'), ('Thomas')) x(name)
```

Result

```
Firstname LastName       First_name Last_Name
Henk      de Vries       Henk       de Vries
Thomas                              Thoma
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Name    VARCHAR(50) = 'Henk de Vries'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @Name) - 1) AS [First Name],
       SUBSTRING(@Name, CHARINDEX(' ', @Name) + 1, LEN(@Name)) AS [Last Name]
```

Comment: FYI: While your answer appears plausible, it has appeared in the 'low quality posts' queue after being flagged for deletion. I suspect this is because it is a code only answer without explanation.

Comment: i have just taken the result set and written the code according to that why it has been considered has low quality post i have written the query according to database standards.@OliverMatthews give a reason for it ???

Answer (score 0):

Use `CHARINDEX` to find the first space, then `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to extract the user's first and last name

```
left(username, charindex(' ', username)-1) firstname, 
right(username, (len(username)-charindex(' ', username))) lastname
```