# Extracting substring from one coloumn and placing it into another SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like so

[filenameAndDate][DateCreated]

the first column looks like this "myvideo/12.12.2012"
and the second column is empty

How would I write a sql query to extract the date from [filenameAndDate] and place it into the [DateCreated] column

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: sorry thought I added that, database is MYSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE [dbo].[FileNames]
SET [DateCreated] = Convert(Date, 
   SUBSTRING(FileNameAndDate, CHARINDEX('/', FileNameAndDate, 0) + 1,
   LEN(fileNameAndDate)))
```

*this is for MSSQL*

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, mate:

```
UPDATE
  <your_table>
SET
  DateCreated = RIGHT(filenameAndDate, 10)
WHERE
  filenameAndDate = 'myvideo/12.12.2012';
```

Suggestion:

- Maybe you can *organize* your table in a way it may not hurt an application based on the content of a field.
- Another one is the format of the date you'll be using, it would be better if you use the **yyyy-mm-dd** format.

PS: this is for MySQL

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[Equivalent of explode() to work with strings in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql)

then use it like

```
insert into blabla (col1, col2) value (val1, SPLIT_STRING(val1,'/',2));
```