# How can I fetch the row of next in rank to the "rank of last id"?

Tags: php, mysql

**Create table**

```
CREATE TABLE goal_implement( id INT, percent INT ); 
INSERT INTO goal_implement VALUES 
  (1,10),
  (2,15),
  (3,20),
  (4,40),
  (5,50),
  (6,20);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT id, percent, FIND_IN_SET( percent, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( percent
ORDER BY percent DESC ) 
FROM goal_implement )
) AS rank 
FROM goal_implement 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

**Result**

```
id  percent rank
6   20      3
5   50      1
4   40      2
3   20      3
2   15      5
1   10      6
```

I don't know how to fetch the `row(rank)` that is next on the last id 
for example: last id's rank is 3!

**Want result**

```
id  percent rank
4   40      2
```

Comment: What functions are you using to do the query ? Mysqli or PDO ?

Comment: # Falt4rm 47 - mysql sir

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the next rank from the (last_id)'s rank - Am i correct? (coz your explanation is a bit confusing) - Means Last_id = 6 - Check rank = 3 so search for rank 4 --> id = 4

Comment: # Falt4rm 47 - search for rank 2 --> id = 4, Sorry for my bad explanation sir

Comment: You can do it in `php` also.

Comment: # b0s3 - can you please show me sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your question we had 2 options of languages :

- Php was easy --> not fun.
- MYSQL --> Your already did a part of the job with Mysql so i finished it this way.

**SQLFIDDLE :** [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e495d/4)

**Steps :**

- Get the last id's rank + Get string of all percentage

  ```
  SELECT FIND_IN_SET( percent, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( percent ORDER BY percent DESC ) 
                        FROM goal_implement )) - 1 into @next_rank
  FROM goal_implement 
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 1;

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( percent ORDER BY percent DESC ) 
  FROM goal_implement into @str_rank;
  ```

This code will get you this :

```
@next_rank       @str_rank
   2          50,40,20,20,15,10
```

**Let's the fun begin (pbm starting - Kappa) :** there is not any explode() function in MYSQL.

- Get percentage related to `@next_rank`  inside `@str_rank`

Best we can do with native function is :

- `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str_rank, ',', @next_rank);`
- Result : `50,40`

But we `'40'` only

--> Let's find / create a function to extract string between +1 and -1 position (Big up to Arman P.)

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STRING(str VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), pos INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos),
   LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos-1)) + 1),
   delim, '');
```

.
`SELECT SPLIT_STRING(@str_rank, ',', @next_rank) into @next_percentage;`

This will store `'40'` in `@next_percentage`

**RESULT : (finally)**

```
SELECT *, @next_rank as rank
FROM goal_implement 
WHERE percent = @next_percentage;
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
id  percent     rank
4     40         2
```

**PHP version  :**

`$Array_test` is supposed the array returned by your query

```
<?php

$array_test = array(array(6,20,3), array(5,50,1), array(4,40,2), 
              array(3,20,3), array(2,15,5), array(1,10,6));


$next_rank = $array_test[0][2] - 1;

foreach($array_test as $row)
    if($row[2] == $next_rank)
    {
        print "<pre>";
        print_r($row);
        print "</pre>";
    }
?>
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
[0] => 4
[1] => 40
[2] => 2
)
```

Source :
[Stackoverflow : Equivalent of explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql)

Comment: ***@Falt4rm -  How can I implement the php code from yours to mine below..... *** 
'<?php    $result2 = mysql_query($query2, $connection);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
     echo   "<tr>       
             <td> {$row['id']} </td>
              <td>{$row['percent']}%</td>
  <td> {$row['rank']} </td>      
            </tr>\n";
} 

?>'

Comment: $result2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);  Verify by printing my array_test & your array query result using print "<pre>"; print_r($array_test); print"</pre>"; Then swap my array_test with your array_query

Comment: If you still get issues - Tell me.

Answer (score 1):

first, get the other id of the last rank... then add one for it. Example below.

```
SELECT id FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE rank = $last_rank AND id != $last_id ORDER BY id DESC;

SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE id = $row['id'] + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from goal_implement where rank=(select (rank-1) 
from goal_implement where id=(select max(id) from goal_implement));
```

O hope you will desired output.