# how divide comma sperated value of a coloumn using mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `tbl_data`. There is an attribute with name `price` where comma separated values i need to divide these comma separated values by a particular 
number.

```
price=2,4,6
```

I need something

```
update tbl_data set price=price/2
```

result required = `1,2,3`

Comment: Explode the array, do your calculations, implode the array = result

Comment: I do not have flexibility to use php .

Comment: Wow, this is ugly. I'd actually suggest that you rethink your schema since it looks as though you really have a relationship there that should be in another table.  However... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql

Comment: You could use a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-routines.html). But personally I would export the data to my localhost (or another server running PHP) and make the changes there and then copy/import the data back to the original DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
update tbl_data set price = replace( replace(price, ',', ''), '"', '' )/2;
```

by using this query 2,4,6 converted to 123 then try to insert comma by character wise with `group_concat()` function

Comment: I wonder what should happen with odd numbers...or are they all even numbers?

Comment: Here data type of price is char so by replace , value 2,4 become 12 and then display with , by using implode or group_concat function

Comment: Matt Browne, Number may be 67.9,89.99,7.098,8 and so on