# SQL count query number of lines per row

Tags: sql, count, sum, jira

I am trying to count the amount of urls we have in field in sql I have googled but cannot find anything !

So for example this could be in field "url" row 1 / id 1

```
url/32432
url/32434
```

So for example this could be field "url" in row 2 / id 2

```
url/32432
url/32488
url/32477
```

So if you were to run the query the count would be 5. There is no comma in between them, only space.

Kind Regards

Scott

Comment: This looks like very bad table design

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of explode() to work with strings in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql)

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: you need a simil to "explode" function in php, check the post flagged as duplicate

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 0):

This is a *very* bad layout for data.  If you have multiple urls per `id`, then they should be stored as separate rows in another table.

But, sometimes we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.   You can do something like this:

```
select (length(replace(urls, 'url', 'urlx')) - length(urls)) as num_urls
```

Note that the specific functions for `length()` and `replace()` might vary, depending on the database.

Comment: Hi Gordon, so its a Jira table i am querying. Basically each time someone calls us, we open a new internal ticket ( not jira ticket ) if this ticket is related to a bug ( Jira ticket ) we then link it to this jira ticket, so one row ie linked_tickets field could have many many urls in it.  I am not sure if the query you gave me is what i am looking for ?

Comment: @ScottRobins . . . You should fix your database so each new link is a new *row* in a table, rather than just appending a new value to an existing column.