# SQL: Split comma separated string list with a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, delimiter

Here is my table structure:

```
id PaymentCond
1  ZBE1, AP1, LST2, CC1
2  VB3, CC1, ZBE1
```

I need to split the column `PaymentCond`, and would love to do that with a simple sql query since I have no clue how to use functions and would love to keep it all simple.

Here is what I already found:

```
SELECT id, 
Substring(PaymentConditions, 1, Charindex(',', PaymentConditions)-1) as COND_1,
Substring(PaymentConditions, Charindex(',', PaymentConditions)+1, LEN(ANGEBOT.STDTXT)) as  COND_2
from Payment
WHERE id = '1'
```

But this only outputs

```
id    COND_1   COND_2
1     ZBE1     AP1, LST2, CC1
```

Is there a way to split everything from `PaymentConditions` to `COND_1`, `COND_2`, `COND_3` and so on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql

Comment: expected out put should be...

Comment: you could use `STRING_SPLIT` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Comment: Am I right in understanding that in your output you want as many columns as there are payment conditions and this to happen dynamically i.e. say for the first row output as - 1|ZBE1|AP1|LST2|CC1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @SchoolYearList nvarchar(max)='2014,2015,2016'
declare @start int=1
declare @length int=4
create table #TempFY(SchoolYear int)
while @start<len(@SchoolYearList)
BEGIN

Insert into #TempFY
select SUBSTRING(@SchoolYearList,@start,@length)
set @start=@start+5
END
Select SchoolYear from #TempFY
```

Comment: It would be nice if you add comments on this awnser.

Answer (score 2):

first create function to split values

```
create function [dbo].[udf_splitstring] (@tokens    varchar(max),
                                   @delimiter varchar(5))
returns @split table (
  token varchar(200) not null )
as



  begin

      declare @list xml

      select @list = cast('<a>'
                          + replace(@tokens, @delimiter, '</a><a>')
                          + '</a>' as xml)

      insert into @split
                  (token)
      select ltrim(t.value('.', 'varchar(200)')) as data
      from   @list.nodes('/a') as x(t)

      return

  end  


 CREATE TABLE #Table1
        ([id] int, [PaymentCond] varchar(20))
    ;

    INSERT INTO #Table1
        ([id], [PaymentCond])
    VALUES
        (1, 'ZBE1, AP1, LST2, CC1'),
        (2, 'VB3, CC1, ZBE1')
    ;
    select id, token FROM #Table1 as t1
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].UDF_SPLITSTRING([PaymentCond],',') as t2
```

output

```
id  token
1   ZBE1
1   AP1
1   LST2
1   CC1
2   VB3
2   CC1
2   ZBE1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new table-valued function in SQL Server **STRING_SPLIT**:

```
DECLARE @tags NVARCHAR(400) = 'aaaa,bbb,,cc,d'  
SELECT * 
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tags, ',')
```

You will get:

[image: Result]

But be careful its availability in your DB: The `STRING_SPLIT` function is available only under compatibility level 130