# MySQL substring from a newline

Tags: mysql

Is there a simple way to only retrieve the info on a new line in a string?
Example:

Some kind of info

Message from somewhere

ref code

Only need to get the second line, so "Message from somewhere"

have done it so have with a mix of substring_index, substring and instr but guessing they must a much easier way for it to be done????
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed use SUBSTRING_INDEX for that. 
But you need to nest the SUBSTRING_INDEX functions

**Create table/insert data.**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  message TEXT
);

INSERT INTO test (message) VALUES("Some kind of info

Message from somewhere

ref code
");
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
  #or you might need to use '\r\n' instead of '\n'
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, '\n', 3), '\n', -1)
FROM
 test
```

**Result**

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, '\n', 3), '\n', -1)  
--------------------------------------------------------------
Message from somewhere
```