# I want to create store Procedure dynamically comma separated columns and values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I pass value to store procedure. The logic is to split value by comma and using a loop.

```
@Colomns Id,Firstname,Lastname
@values 1,'foo','bar'
```

Query should be

```
Select * from user where Id = 1 and Firstname = 'foo' and Lastname = 'bar'
```

Comment: Search for mysql split string and come back with the code you have written if you have a problem.

Comment: maybe duplicate on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Just use `substring_index()` or `concat()`:

```
Select *
from user
where concat_ws(Id, firstname, lastname) = @param;
```

Then, fix the stored procedure to take three parameters!  There is no advantage to putting three values into a string, rather than passing in three separate values.