# select all rows where column contains value from comma separated values

Tags: php

I have mysql table (say mytable1) where values are stored as comma separated values in a column.

Now I want to fetch all rows in another table (say mytable2) where column unique_id contains value from above comma separated values.

e.g. 
mytable1 contains multiple rows with different unique_ids including following two given in $string.

I want to fetch only those two rows where row one unique_id is ABCD1 And row two where unique_id is BCDE2. these two unique_ids are not fixed. they may be different from different rows in mytable1

e.g.

```
$string = "ABCD1,BCDE2"; (retrieved from mytable1)

$query = "select * from mytable2 where unique_id = "values from $string ????";
```

What right $query should be ?

I couldn't figure it out with IN or FIND_IN_SET ...

your help is appreciated....

Comment: WHERE  unique_id IN ("ABCD1,BCDE2")

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
$query = "select * from mytable2 where unique_id IN ('ABCD1','BCDE2');
```

or in one line:

```
$query = "select * from mytable2 where unique_id IN (select unique_id from mytable1 where variable='somecondition');
```

this nested query for `mytable1` should return only 1 column

Comment: thnx.. I will try with this solution and will let you know...

Answer (score 1):

```
$idsArray = explode(",", $string);       // this will contain ["ABCD1", "BCDE2", ...]
$idsQuoted = array_map(function ($id) {  // each id will be surrounded by single-quotes '
    return "'{$id}'";
}, $idsArray);
$idsString = join(", ", $idsQuoted);     // join all ids by a comma
$query = "select * from mytable2 where unique_id in ({$idsString})";
```

Note that this won't work, if the `$string` var is an empty string, because databases usually don't support empty `IF` clause.

Comment: thnx.. I will surely try with this solution and will let you know... I think this is what I need.....

Comment: I tried this. It worked but it is fetching only one record with value at first in comma separated list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql) to "explode" the string, and then you need just:

```
$query = "select * from mytable2 where unique_id IN SPLIT_STRING('$string', ',', 1)";
```

be sure to sanitize the string, which should not contains any `'`

Comment: thnx.. I will try with this solution and will let you know...

Answer (score 0):

Following your `$string = "ABCD1,BCDE2"; (retrieved from mytable1)`

You have to split the string with comma separated.

e.g. `$string = explode(",", $string);`, so it will be `$string[0] = "ABCD1"` and `$string[1] = "BCDE2"`. And you can customize your query with these.