# Split string with sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I use MySqlWorkbench and I have one metric as a long string like

`metric (AAAA,B,CCCC,DD)  (AAAAAAA,BBB,C,DD,EEE)`    
This metric is varible and I would like to do a split by coma, how can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: No easy way - frequently asked ,search for mysql split string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql