# Extract data between two characters(=,/,+,etc)

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a column name(fle) and the data looks like /vr/gg/ercs/nyt_dte/segment/xml/subnetwor/=hhh/bvth=lhyt012
I need to extract the data which is between = and / example hhh.

Comment: Check this :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5928675/17254553 It looks like your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by finding indexes of both characters and using `substring` function. Here's example query:

```
declare @sampleString nvarchar(500) = '/vr/gg/ercs/nyt_dte/segment/xml/subnetwor/=hhh/bvth=lhyt012';

select
    substring(@sampleString, OpeningCharIndex + 1, ClosingCharIndex - OpeningCharIndex - 1)
from (
    select 
        OpeningCharIndex,
        CHARINDEX('/', @sampleString, OpeningCharIndex) ClosingCharIndex
    from (
        select
            CHARINDEX('=', @sampleString) OpeningCharIndex
    ) a
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the data you gave us:

```
create table MyTable (
  MyColumn varchar(100)
)

insert into MyTable values ('/vr/gg/ercs/nyt_dte/segment/xml/subnetwor/=hhh/bvth=lhyt012')
```

This simple select is what you want:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
    MyColumn, 
    charindex('=', MyColumn) + 1,
    CHARINDEX('/', substring(MyColumn, charindex('=', MyColumn) + 2, LEN(MyColumn)))
)
from MyTable
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/374677/3

Comment: @UmairChib if this solved your problem, do not forget to mark it as accepted answer, please (and optionally upvote it).