# Explode the values in the database

Tags: php, wordpress, implode

I want to implode my id values that I keep from database.

My data in database
`wp_badges`

```
id    badges        value_id
----  ------        --------
1     Outloot       2719,3314
```

My id values that I saved as value is actually become my product id

Following my code :`PHP`

```
 $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT values_id FROM wp_badges");
    foreach($result as $value){

     $value->values_id;
    }
    $arr = array($value->values_id);
    echo '"'.implode('","',$arr).'"';
```

Here is the output:**"2719,3314"**

But the output I wanted was to get each element with double quotes

The output I want:**"2719","3314"**

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql ?

Comment: If you have a comma separated string, putting it in an array and running `implode()` on it doesn't make sense since that would implode an array with that string as one single element.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent of explode() to work with strings in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing things in the wrong place, the explode and echo has to be inside the loop or you will only ever do anything with the last occurance in the `$result` array.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT values_id FROM wp_badges");
foreach($result as $value){
    $bits = explode(',',$value->values_id);
    echo '"' . implode('","', $bits) . '"<br>';
}
```

RESULT

```
"123","456"<br>
"923","956"<br>
```