# How can I add brackets to each word of a string which contains multiple words in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I add brackets to each word of a string which contains multiple words in SQL? For example, I have:

```
string example = 'word1,word2,word3,word4,word5'
```

How can I convert it to something like this:

```
string example = '[word1],[word2],[word3],[word4],[word5]'
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not replace all occurences of a comma with `],[`, append a `[`, and prepend a `]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a combination of `REPLACE()` and string concatenation:

```sql
SELECT val, CONCAT('[', REPLACE(val, ',', '],[') , ']') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

On MySQL 8+, we can use a regex replacement:

```sql
SELECT val, REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '([^,]+)', '[$1]') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```