# print the value before the colon in the line

Tags: mysql

I recently started studying SQL and came across a problem that I can’t find an answer to. If anyone knows how to implement this, please provide me with information.
I have a table and a column that has a row with the value 1:2:3. I need to set the following code:

`SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY testColumn DESC`
Need to define testColumn as something that can get the first value before the colon from the string in testColumn, that is - 1

Comment: If your column is called `testColumn`, then the first value of your string is `SUBSTRING_INDEX(testColumn, ':', 1)`

Comment: MySQL itself won't "print" anything. Anything else would be possible with the options at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for this, use a sql function to split the column.

```sql
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column, ':', 1) AS testColumn
FROM 
    test
ORDER BY
testColumn DESC;
```